# The File System Access API createWritable() method works inside console, but not in script

Tags: javascript, file-system-access-api

I'm currently getting to grips with the File System Access API for a future project, and I am having difficulty using the createWritable() method in the line:

`const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();`

When I trigger it, it gives me the error:

`TypeError: fileHandle.createWritable is not a function`

However, when I run this exact command in the console, it works perfectly.

I'm using windows 10 if that's relevant at all. Thanks for the help.

I will include my relevant HTML and JS below:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
    <button class="read-btn">Read</button>
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
    <button class="create-btn">Create</button>
    <button class="write-btn">Write</button>
</body>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
const readBtn = document.querySelector(".read-btn");
const createBtn = document.querySelector(".create-btn")
const writeBtn = document.querySelector(".write-btn");
const txt = document.querySelector("#txt");

// Store a ref to file handle
let fileHandle;
let contents;

// === READ FROM A FILE SYSTEM ===
readBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    // open filepicker
    [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
    // Returns a file object
    const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
    // Runs text method on returned file object to access text
    contents = await file.text();
    // Inputs contents into txt
    txt.value = contents;
});

// === WRITE TO FILESYSTEM ===

// Create a new file
async function getNewFileHandle() {
    const options = {
        types: [
            {
                description: 'Text Files',
                accept: {
                    'text/plain': ['.txt'],
                },
            },
        ],
    };
    const handle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(options);
    return handle;
}

// Save changes to disk
async function writeFile(fileHandle) {
    contents = txt.value;
    // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
    const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
    // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
    await writable.write(contents);
    // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
    await writable.close();
}

createBtn.addEventListener("click", getNewFileHandle)

writeBtn.addEventListener("click", writeFile)
```

Comment: Is this script being served over HTTPS?

Comment: @esqew no it's not, I'm using the liver server extension for VS code. That didn't occur to me. Thanks man, you're a life saver! Do you want to submit it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN documentation, [`window.showOpenFilePicker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker), [`FileSystemFileHandle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle), and [`FileSystemWritableFileStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemWritableFileStream) are only supported in secure contexts:

> ### Secure context
>
> This feature is available only in [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)
> (HTTPS), in some or all [supporting
> browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker#browser_compatibility).

It's my understanding that the "Live Server" extension for VS Code would not meet this requirement, but the developer console would.